# How to create a Bitmap from an image file in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

How to load an image file (on SD card) into a Bitmap on Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)